# How to fix preview tab bug in Android Studio Arctic Fox

Tags: android, android-studio

I update my android studio version to Arctic Fox.
But after update of Android Studio to this version, it shows blurry items in preview tab.

My preview tab image:

[image]

I used windows 10 for OS.

How can I fix it?

Comment: :( I am having related problems to Android Layout Previews too. Slightly different but I don't have your exact problem and don't know the answer. I feel alone with my problem as if I am the only one who has layout rendering problems after Artic Fox. So I noticed your downvote and gave you an upvote. It's probably a legit problem as mine is.

Comment: Use Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1

Answer (score 3):

**Short Answer: Downgrade to Android Studio 4.2.2.**

Android Studio Arctic Fox - made major changes. However, it created new issues that didn't exist. It needs a patch. I even tried the latest patch of Android Studio Arctic Fox (2020.3.1) Patch 1 - August/18, It didn't solve it. So, I had to downgrade to Android Studio 4.2.2, which is relatively more stable.

When downgrading to Android Studio 4.2.2, you have to change the following

- distributionUrl in graddle-wrapper.properties

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-bin.zip

- classpath in build.gradle (Project)

> classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2"

Answer (score 1):

This Same Happened to me and unfortunately, there is no perfect fix.
It is due to scaling according to your device display size.
Android Studio currently supports Display Scaling of 100% , 200% etc.
So if your device have 150% scaling, this error occurs...

You can temporarily fix it by the following way, but you have to adjust your font size accordingly.
Open Android Studio > Help > Edit custom properties > If one is not already there, you will be prompted to create one.
Then enter the following :

```
hidpi=false
```

Then press enter and close Android Studio (Restart it).
Then you can see everything in a small size, but the preview tab will be fixed. Then Go to Settings and adjust font size of your choice (On both editor and whole IDE).
This is only a temporary solution. And many others are facing this same issue after the updates including old versions of Android Studio.

You can also try changing scaling from Windows Settings (You should set scaling to 100%), but it will affect your Entire OS

Comment: Yes... I already said that this fix is not permanent. But trying this helped me to reduce the problem on screen preview... Google should fix this problem through a update since this problem exists for users who update android studio even on older versions.....

Answer (score 0):

You can do (+) zoom button click in layout preview and try using layout preview in more zoom, this is only thing working for me to see things clear