# Android XML Preview Unclear After Update to Arctic Fox

Tags: android, android-studio, android-xml, android-studio-arctic-fox

After updated to Arctic Fox version, the xml layout previewer looks fuzzy, unclear, see below:

[image]

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: Just adjust the zoom?

Comment: @javdromero That will be very painful. It was clear in previous version.

Comment: I have seen quite a few posts here regarding this, maybe it's an IDE issue as usual. I don't trust the stable updates these days because minute but important things like these break for no reason

Comment: Hi this is related to Android Studio Arctic Fox version. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68587416/how-to-fix-preview-tab-bug-in-android-studio-arctic-fox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the latest version (BumbleBee) fixed this problem.

Answer (score 4):

It helped me: **Help** => **Edit Custom VM Options** => Paste "**-Dsun.java2d.uiScale.enabled=false**" and restart the IDE.

For more information, click [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007994999-HiDPI-configuration).

Comment: Thanks. A working solution. Should be an accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Not just XML preview, the Jetpack Compose preview is also very blurry on my Macbook. I tried the old trick Help > Edit custom properties and add:

hidpi=false

But this did not work (maybe it will work on Windows, you can try). Currently I have to revert back to Android Studio 4.2.2 .

Answer (score 0):

My issue is resolved when I installed the Oracle Java JDK 11 and then changed the JAVA_HOME directory from JDK1.8_xxx to latest JDK I installed and then I restarted my system
[image: Image after doing this]

Answer (score 0):

I has same issue and i have been used all tricks and method but preview was not showing, at last i used below code and it worked.

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    }
}
```