# Android Studio is displaying text blurred

Tags: android, android-layout

My android studio is not showing views properly as you can see in screenshots. What causes that?[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKzbZ.png) [image: image 2]

[image]ng

Comment: It's just the preview's zoom. It doesn't affect your app.

Comment: @javdromero why this happen? On some views, it looks really worse. Look at the button https://drive.google.com/file/d/16xoPn-7kIEEY8D8nKQweLkO9j9CkqLnY/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

This is an error that happens time to time. I think if a lot of patches or features coming in or beeing changed/upgraded. I saw this behaviour reported multiple times.

Some help to make it disappear [even if only for a short time]:

1. Scaling from 125% to 100% or vice versa (*Further Settings)
2. Force Refresh Layout (Shortcut "R")
3. If point 2 doesn't help `File` -> `Invalide Caches/Restart`

---

*Further Settings:

It depends on your monitor resolution. The percentage in your screen settings will be the equivalent correct rendered percentage in your Android Studio.

E.g.:

100% Screen = 100% Android Studio (125% in Android Studio would be blurry)

Or

125% Screen = 125% Android Studio (100% in Android Studio would be blurry)

[image]

Comment: thanks for answer Actually, I have just this issue on design inspector. other sides of android studio don't seem to blurred. is there any possibility to increase scale of android studio to 125%?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Yes in the design window, there is in the bottom left corner "+" and "-". if you press the plus twice you will increase to 125%. Feel free to tick my answer as correct to keep stackoverflow serving as an encyclopedia. Thanks

Comment: Actually even though I changed scaling in windows settings, the problem is still continue. I download android studio 4.2.2 and this version doesn't have that problem. It seem there is a bug in arctic fox version. Please see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68587416/how-to-fix-preview-tab-bug-in-android-studio-arctic-fox

Comment: Yes, that's why I wrote it happens time to time :) That was in the past also. It is when something getting updated, seems to be unstable then. Hope I could help you even a bit. Cheers :)